# Is there a way to compare the size of format date in Android room query?

Tags: android, sql, android-room

I'll show you the code first

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM plan WHERE (DATETIME(startDate, '%Y-%m-%d') <= :temp OR DATETIME(endDate, '%Y-%m-%d') >= :temp) OR specificDate = :temp")
fun getPlanByDate(temp: String): List<PlannerEntity>
```

Inside the table named `plan`, there are `startDate`, `endDate`, and `specificDate` columns. Based on the date called `temp`, I want to get only data belonging to `temp`. The format of `temp` is "yyyy-MM-dd". The `startDate` and `endDate` are stored in "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" format, so you can see my efforts to change it to "yyyy-MM-dd" format. How can I change the format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm` to `yyyy-MM-dd` format?

Comment: If you have your dates in a `date` datatype, you'll never have these issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I change the format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm to yyyy-MM-dd format?

Use `date(the_column)` or `strftime('%Y-%m-%d',the_column)`

However, I believe that your logic is incorrect as it will only be if the endDate is less than the startDate that a row will be excluded.
You possibly want `AND` rather than `OR`  as per :-

```
.... WHERE (date(startDate) <= :temp AND date(endDate) >=  :temp) OR date(specificDate) = :temp
```

or alternately the simpler :-

```
.... WHERE  :temp BETWEEN date(startDate) AND date(endDate) OR date(specificDate) = :temp
```

You may wish to refer to [SQLite Date And Time Functions](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) from which covers the `date`, `datetime`, `time`, `julianday` and `strftime` functions (i.e. date manipulation).